# How to archiving multi eclipse product in single packaging and change the location of config.ini and p2 paths?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse project which is having 2 features and I need to build a 2 different product in single archive using Maven-Tycho.

I want my build eclipse product structure should be in the single archive
[image]

Q1. jre, plugins and features should be kept in common default directories?

Q2. Need to create separate configuration folders under configuration for each products

```
  - configuration
    - configuration_a1 
    - configuration_a2 
- Under each sub configuration folder need separate ini file and p2
```

repository should be created

I tried by adding

-Declipse.p2.data.area==@config.dir/./p2

-Dosgi.configuration.area=@config.dir/configuration_ab12/

But it is still creating p2 folder under installation location and
sub configuration folder is nor creating

Q3. I also want to rename default executable file(eclipse.exe) and ini file(eclipse.ini) to individual executable for 2 products i.e a1.exe, a2.exe, a1.ini and a2.ini?
Ans: This is clear, this can be done via .product file(open .product file and go to launching tab and change the launching name)

My Project structure is something looks like below:

```
myproject
 - myproject.a1.plugin
   -pom.xml
 - myproject.a1.feature
   -pom.xml
 - myproject.a2.plugin
   -pom.xml
 - myproject.a2.feature
   -pom.xml
 - myproject.product.plugin
    - a1.product (only contains a1 feature)
    - a2.product (contains both a1 & a2 feature)
   -pom.xml
 - myproject.target.plugin
  - myproject.a1.target (target file)
  - myproject.a2.target (target file)
  - pom.xml
-pom.xml(parent)
```

Comment: The question sounds like the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me and not being focused on a single issue. [The name of the executable can be configured in the product configuration file](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/06a26209e61801ec9d8133e3e4dbadf24c49bf4b/product/idealized.product#L18).

Comment: @howlger edited the question, hope it will be clear to you now?

Comment: It's still the XY problem because the question doesn't explain why two products are needed rather than one product consisting of two applications.